# Можно включить чанки в modx в статичных файлах?

Tags: modx

Попросили сделать статичные страницы, на динамичных загружались чанки статичных просто загружается текст. вроде `[[$menu]]`. Подскажите как сделать?

Пытался настроить использовать вложенные урлы (`use_alias_path`) -> чтобы ссылки были `site.ru/blog/hello.html`, напортачил с `htaccess`. Сказали делать статические. Не подскажите как быть?

Как включить чанк не в шаблоне а в статичном файле и реально ли это вообще сделать?

Comment: Какие трудности в настройке "вложенных url"? Задачей стоит, как я понял. получить url вида `site.ru/каегория/ресурс.html`. Сделайте соответствующую структуру ресурсов. Кстати `htaccess` трогать нет нужды, всё настраивается в системных настройках.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modx revo умеет делать сслылки вида `site.ru/blog/hello.html` "из коробки" если включить системную настройку "`Использовать вложенные URL`" (`use_alias_path`). Единственное с чем может возникнуть дополнительные проблемы в общении с такими клиентами - вместо `site.ru/blog/` - могут потребовать `site.ru/blog/index.html` - но и это решается через заморозку урла директории `site.ru/blog/`.

Comment: да, я отрыл на блоге эту информацию и тронул htaccess случайно забил туда дефолтную строки с блога, поменял use_alias_path на тру, сохранил во вкладке рядом  открыл сайт, и полезла ошибка 503, я думал сейчас исправлю, но правил htaccess, и безрезультатно. Почему-то настройки сбились в путях в конфигурационных файлах, знакомый мне помог, но по 2 кругу портачить рука не поднялась, на работе я не задержался надолго)

Comment: В любом случае спасибо за помощь